# How to find the pre-defined rollover condition of elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm reading the elasticsearch documents, about the rollover feature(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-rollover-index.html).

If someone pre-defined a rollover condition for a index, for example:

```
POST /logs_write/_rollover 
{
  "conditions": {
    "max_age":   "7d",
    "max_docs":  1000,
    "max_size":  "5gb"
  }
}
```

So the logs_write will rollover in 7 days, or more than 1000 docs, or more the 5gb size.

- **Question 1**: How can I get this condition? By GET request cant't get the rollover condition:

  ```
  GET http://127.0.0.1:9200/logs_write/_rollover
  {
      "error": "Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/logs_write/_rollover] and method [GET], allowed: [POST]",
      "status": 405
  }
  ```
- **Question 2**: Does the rollover run manually, or it can be run automatically according to the condition? (My local test shows it can only run manually, which does not make sense.)

Forgive me this maybe a stupid question but I haven't find a clue, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I will answer the questions myself after days of research.

Conditions of rollover cannot be got. It can only be run manually every-time of the rollover, so it's not essential to get the previous conditions.

Correct me if my understanding is wrong. Thanks!